# why is shadow fading also called slow fading and large-scale fading?

Tags: wireless, communication

I've encountered several similar claims regarding shadow fading on several books, and have some difficulty understanding them.

(1) Shadow fading is called slow fading because the duration of the fade may last for multiple seconds or minutes.

If the obstacles are still between the transmitter and receiver, why would the fade last only up to minutes, instead of forever until the obstacles are gone?

(2) Shadow fading is called large-scale fading; on the contrary, fading caused by multipath is called small-scale fading.

To my understanding, shadow fading is due to large obstacles such as buildings, that's the "large-scale". Where does the "small-scale" in multipath fading come from? Obviously, reflection of large buildings can cause multipath.